# React modal dialog re-renders parent component - how to approach this

Tags: reactjs, dialog, modal-dialog, reactive

I have a parent component with reactive vars that are populated with data from a Mongo collection. The child modal dialog modifies this information, causing a re-render of the parent component — and also the modal dialog.

Obviously the modal dialog shouldn't be re-rendered. I tried lifting the open/close state to the parent, but the re-renders still occur.

What are ways that I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance!

I tried lifting the open/close state to the parent, but the re-renders still occur.

Comment: `Obviously the modal dialog shouldn't be re-rendered.` Actually, the default behavior in react is that if a component rerenders, its children rerender also. If you want to take steps to prevent this, look into [useMemo](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) and [React.memo](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo#memo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memoization using React.memo or useMemo:
Wrap your modal component with React.memo to prevent unnecessary re-renders if its props haven't changed.

```
const ModalComponent = React.memo(({ isOpen, onClose }) => {
// Your modal content here
});

    
// In parent component
return (
<div>
{/* Other parent content */}
<ModalComponent isOpen={modalOpen} onClose={toggleModal} />
</div>
);
```

Alternatively you can use useMemo

```
const modalComponent = useMemo(() => <ModalComponent isOpen={modalOpen} onClose={toggleModal} />, [modalOpen]);

// In parent component
return (
  <div>
    {/* Other parent content */}
    {modalComponent}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks Arya V L, the useMemo worked out perfecty